# JSF and PrettyFaces: Error 500 performing resource injection when I try to rewrite a url page

Tags: java

I have a situation in my project. I'm using PrettyFaces v3.3.3 on it for url rewrite.

this is the error i'm getting every time a try to access a configured link:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean userBean
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
```

But when I'm not using prettyfaces I have no issues.

pretty-config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                      http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

    <url-mapping id="cadastro_usuario">
        <pattern value="/cadastro_usuario" />
        <view-id value="/pages/user/cadastro.htm"/>
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

Please help me.

---

StackTrace:

```
Jun 29, 2015 10:56:38 AM com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetRenderer getNavigationCase
WARNING: JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt11.
Jun 29, 2015 10:56:38 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/pages/user/cadastro.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean userBean
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:77)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:187)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:147)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:65)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:37)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.project.repository.infra.UsuariosHibernate.todos(UsuariosHibernate.java:22)
    at com.project.beans.UserBean.init(UserBean.java:73)
    ... 85 more

Jun 29, 2015 10:56:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.project.repository.infra.UsuariosHibernate.todos(UsuariosHibernate.java:22)
    at com.project.beans.UserBean.init(UserBean.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:77)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:187)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:147)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:65)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:37)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 29, 2015 10:56:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/ProjectJSF] threw exception [An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean userBean] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.project.repository.infra.UsuariosHibernate.todos(UsuariosHibernate.java:22)
    at com.project.beans.UserBean.init(UserBean.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:77)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:187)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:147)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:65)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:37)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:83)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The class that retrieves the Hibernate Session from HibernateUtil Class.

```
package com.project.util;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.Severity;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class FacesUtil {

    public static Object getRequestAttribute(String name) {
        FacesContext cxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ecxt = cxt.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ecxt.getRequest();
        return request.getAttribute(name);
    }

}


package com.project.util;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.project.repository.IMulta;
import com.project.repository.ITitular;
import com.project.repository.IUsuario;
import com.project.repository.infra.MultasHibernate;
import com.project.repository.infra.TitularesHibernate;
import com.project.repository.infra.UsuariosHibernate;

public class Repositorio implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1921518600016820244L;

    private Session getSession() {
        return (Session) FacesUtil.getRequestAttribute("session");
    }

}
```

I'm passing the session value to the app using a Servlet filter

```
package com.project.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

@WebFilter(servletNames={"Faces Servlet"})
public class HibernateSessionFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction trx = null;

        try {
            trx = session.beginTransaction();

            request.setAttribute("session", session);
            System.out.println("Init ...");

            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            trx.commit();
            System.out.println("closing ...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(trx != null) {
                trx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: I see you are missing a <`rewrite>` tag. what is the url in the browser that you are trying to launch??

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but it didn't  work.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the url that you are trying to launch?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ProjectJSF/cadastro_usuario

Comment: Well then, if you can please provide the full stackTrace, the answer should be there somewhere. Also the code for Bean, faces-config and your jsf page. Do you have any @PostConstruct annotation in your bean?

Comment: Yes I have that annotation in my bean. could it be the source of all exceptions?

Comment: Could be! As I said can you put all the stackTrace here and the bean code as well. Are you trying to fetch the session from `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` in that annotated method? Can you show these things?

Comment: Yes I'm using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` in a class that is called inside a method with that annotation to retrieve HibernateSession. Here is the class.

Comment: yes please add that class and a stacktrace could be the best thing to solve this! in case you are doing this, `session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false); ` change it to, `session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true); ` Pass `true` instead of false.

Comment: updated my answer need code for `UsuariosHibernate.java`. Thats where the exception lies. I guess session would be null

Answer (score 0):

**Updating my answer** since the error stackTrace has been provided. 
StackTrace says you have a `NullPointerException` at `UsuariosHibernate.java:22`

Can you post the code for `UsuariosHibernate.java`?

You have a lot of flaws here. The main Culprit is Using HibernateSession instead of HTTPSession.

- Import HTTPSession instead of HibernateSession in Repositorio class.
- Do you have a `getUsuarios();` method in `Repositorio` class?
- Also you seem to be mixing `HTTPSession` with `HibernateSession` in
  `HibernateSessionFilter`. HTTPSession should be imported.

Please fix these things first!

You are missing `<rewrite>` tag. Add the tag in pretty-config file as shown below,

```
<rewrite match="/pages/user/cadastro.htm" substitute="/cadastro_usuario" redirect="301"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'm using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` in a class that is called inside a method with that annotation to retrieve HibernateSession. Here is the class.

```
package com.project.beans;    
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

import com.project.model.Role;
import com.project.model.User;
import com.project.repository.IUsuario;
import com.project.util.FacesUtil;
import com.project.util.Repositorio;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6686020001982914849L;
    private User user;
    private List<User> users;
    private List<User> filteredUsers;
    private int totalUsers;
    private Repositorio repositorio;

    public void setFilteredUsers(List<User> filteredUsers) {
        this.filteredUsers = filteredUsers;
    }

    public List<User> getFilteredUsers() {
        return filteredUsers;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public UserBean() {
        user = new User();
    }

    public Role[] getRoles() {
        return Role.values();
    }

    public String addUser() {
        IUsuario usuarios = repositorio.getUsuarios();
        user.setCreated(Calendar.getInstance());
        usuarios.guardar(user);
        users.add(user);
        FacesUtil.adicionaMensagem(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, FacesUtil.getMensagemI18n("sucesso"));

        return "/pages/user/cadastro";
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        repositorio =  new Repositorio();
        IUsuario usuario = repositorio.getUsuarios();
        users = usuario.todos();
    }

    public User read() {
        IUsuario usuarios = repositorio.getUsuarios();
        usuarios.porCodigo(user.getId());
        return user;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesUtil.adicionaMensagem(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, ((User)event.getObject()).getNome());
    }

    public int getTotalUsers() {
        totalUsers = users.size();
        return totalUsers;
    }

    public void update() {
        IUsuario usuarios = repositorio.getUsuarios();
        usuarios.guardar(user);
        FacesUtil.adicionaMensagem(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, FacesUtil.getMensagemI18n("sucesso"));
    }

    public void deleteUser(User u) {
        IUsuario usuarios = repositorio.getUsuarios();
        usuarios.apagar(u);
        FacesUtil.adicionaMensagem(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, FacesUtil.getMensagemI18n("sucesso_apagar"));
    }
}
```